# How to write script to perform sum of integers in jenkins , by taking input from parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

I want to perform sum of integers (c = a+b) in jenkins, initially i have defined the value of a by giving def a = 5,  but I want to take values of b from parameters . So i added string parameter but this is not considering as integer ,instead it is just attaching the 2 values , is there any way so that i can take inputs of  b from parameter and perform addition
the pipeline is as follows

pipeline {
agent any
stages {
stage('Stage 1') {
steps {
script{

```
             def a = 5; 
             //def b = "${params.inputvalue}";
             c = "${a + b}" ;
             
             echo "value of c is  ${c}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

in parameter if i give value of b as 2 the output it's giving as 25 but the expected output is 7 i.e 2+5

Comment: use your groovy syntax editor for generate scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by converting string parameter to integer

```
  int a = 10;
  stage('arithmetic stage') {
    int b = params.Value;
    c = a + b;
    echo "${c}"
    }
```

here "Value" is String parameter name .